# Run a docker container from inside java program

Tags: java, docker, processbuilder

I try to run a docker container from inside a java program, but the docker container won't run.

When I execute this command I use for the process builder in the terminal the container starts and everything works.

I printed the working directory inside the java program and this is the right directory to start the docker container.

I also changed the command to:

```
String[] dockerCommand = new String[] {"java", "-cp", "target/MavenAsteroidsServer-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar", "asteroidsserver.AsteroidsServer", "1600", "1600", "127.0.1.1", "8851", "8901"};
```

This worked, so running the program without a docker container works.

This is the code I used to run the docker container from inside the java program:

```
String[] dockerCommand = new String[] {"docker", "run", "-it", "--rm", "--net=\"host\"", "-p", "8901:8901", "-v", "\"$PWD\":/app", "-w", "/app", "demo/maven:3.3-jdk-8", "java", "-cp", "target/MavenAsteroidsServer-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar", "asteroidsserver.AsteroidsServer", "1600", "1600", "127.0.1.1", "8851", "8901"};

ProcessBuilder probuilder = new ProcessBuilder(dockerCommand);

Process process;
try {
    process = probuilder.start();
    int status = process.waitFor();
} catch (InterruptedException e) {
} catch (IOException ex) {
}
```

I want the container to run, but nothing happens. Also, I get no error messages when I try to catch them in the try and catch block (not shown in the code)

Comment: Does the process write anything that is readable through the input or error streams?

Comment: Is your command run with root perms? because it's required by Docker's CLI…

Comment: Ya it does, but you don't see it, because it's not redirected anywhere. The server spawned in the container here should connect back to the java program which created it, but it doens't. When I run the command in the terminal or without the docker container in the program it does.

Comment: I did this to have root perms: https://askubuntu.com/questions/477551/how-can-i-use-docker-without-sudo

Answer (score 1):

Most ways to programmatically run commands from programs don't involve a shell and so don't do any of the nice things that shells do like, for example, variable interpolation.  In particular, this pair of arguments:

```
..., "-v", "\"$PWD\":/app", ...
```

tells Docker (I think) to create a new named volume named `"$PWD"` (as in quote, dollars, P, W, D, quote), and mount the new empty volume on `/app` in the container.  Nothing would cause this to get expanded to the name of the current directory or remove the extra quotes.

Comment: I've changed the docker image, now it can be started with the command: 'docker run -it --rm --net=host -P server:latest'. Still I have the same problem, I can start it from terminal, but can't inside a java program.